# SQL Server get column not in Group By clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by, max

How to get the following result from this table?

```
ID1|ID2| Date  
----------------------
1  | 1 | 01-01-2014  
1  | 2 | 02-01-2014  
2  | 3 | 03-01-2014
```

I want to get ID1 & ID2 for the maximum date when grouped by ID1

Result:

```
1,2  
2,3
```

My code:

```
SELECT 
    ID1, MAX(DATE) 
FROM 
    Table 
GROUP BY 
    ID1
```

I need something like

```
SELECT 
    ID1, ID2, MAX(DATE) 
FROM 
    Table 
GROUP BY 
    ID1
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 8):

There's three ways to do it.

One, a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.ID1, t1.ID2, t2.MAX_DATE
FROM Table t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID1, MAX(DATE) AS "MAX_DATE" FROM Table GROUP BY ID1) t2
    ON t1.ID1 = t2.ID2
```

Or you can use the `OVER()` clause if you're on SQL Server 2005+, recent versions of Oracle, or PostgreSQL (and most recent things not MySQL or MariaDB):

```
SELECT ID1,
    ID2,
    MAX(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY ID1)
FROM Table
```

Or you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.ID1, 
    t1.ID2, 
    (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM Table WHERE ID1 = t1.ID1)
FROM Table t1
```

Comment: With the first method, It's not possible to join on `t2.ID2` if it's not selected in the subquery and in order to select  it, it should also be added to the group by clause which ruins everything. It's what I'm facing in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by joining the table to the aggregate, like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM 
    Table t 
     INNER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            ID1, 
            MAX(Date) MaxDate 
        FROM Table 
        GROUP BY ID1
      ) MaxDate ON
        t.ID1 = MaxDate.ID1 AND
        t.Date = MaxDate.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by ID1 order by [date] desc) as seq
 FROM Table1
) T
WHERE T.seq =1
```

Comment: This one is brilliant